# subtracting winning probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, chessboard

Two players play a game of chess. When they get home, they use a computer to analyze the game.

For each position of the game, the computer knows what move is best, and it assigns a winning probability to that move $P(c)$. The computer is also able to calculate a winning probability to the move that the player had made in that position $P(p)$. These probabilities are in the range [0.0-1.0].

So, for each position $x$ of the game we can calculate a delta, which represents a drop of winning probability.

$\delta(x) = P(c) - P(p)$

If the player played the best move, then this delta will be $0$. A value of $0.1$ or higher would mean that it is a terrible move. ($10\%$ drop of the winning probability). In the extremely rare case, that the human player surpassed the computer and played something brilliant, the delta could be negative.

Next if we make a sum for the delta's for all moves, we get a sum-of-lost-opportunities. In other words, a low sum will indicate a high level of play, and a high sum will indicate a low level of play.

Unfortunately we cannot use this number to compare the level of play of different games, because not all games have the same number of turns. So, we should divide it by the number of turns.

$Level = \dfrac{\sum \delta}{\# moves}$

*The next step, (which is outside the scope of this question) is to scale this Level to an ELO rating (which is an international system for ratings of chess players).*

**But already I have some doubt about all the above.**

One of the things that I have doubts about is the subtracting of the winning probabilities. I think the following is actually not entirely correct.

$\delta(x) = P(c) - P(p)$

It raises the question: What is worst?
(a drop of $1$ to $0.95$)  vs  (a drop of $0.5$ to $0.45$)
My gut feeling tells me that the latter is worst.

**Could somebody explain to me how I could calculate the delta in a non-linear way?**

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: There's a lot here that isn't clear.  First of all, how could delta be negative?  Even if it is true that the human made a better move than the computer could understand, the computer would not know that.  So, are you overwriting the ranks the computer assigns?  How?  Second, this is a subjective measure...there is no objective standard as to what function you should consider.  But, to your question, you could simply measure the percent deviation.  Thus if the computer likes move $c$ but I choose move $p$, you could compute $\frac {P(c)-P(p)}{P(p)}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks :)

Comment: @lulu The computer does not consider all moves. So, when it thinks it has "the best move", in a rare case it may be wrong. i.e. if it didn't consider the move of the player. So, once it starts calculating the winning percentage of that human move it may suddenly (out of nowhere) change its mind, and recognize that the human move was better after all.

Comment: Fair enough.  But that just stresses the subjective nature of the weighting process.  At best you are measuring how closely the player's strategy hues to the computer's.  To connect that to a more objective ranking, I think you'd want to compare whatever score you got to something connected with actual win/loss.  If my score is consistently lower than yours, does that predict that you'll probably beat me?  As a proxy for that, you could compare to the standard rankings.  Which matches the standard rankings better...additive difference (as you wrote) or multiplicative difference (as I wrote).